# Kohana: What is the best way to serve robots.txt?

Tags: php, web-applications, kohana, robots.txt, kohana-3.2

In our web app we're redirecting all 404's to a pretty error page, but for robots.txt we need to server a default page (or return 404), else google won't index us.

Should I be adding a route to bootstrap.php specifically for http://www.mydomain.com/robots.txt?

Or should I be doing this through .htaccess?

Was there a cleaner approach I overlooked?

Comment: Why not just add a robots.txt? Wouldn't that just be easier and more robust, less chance of failure?

Comment: what does this have to do with google indexing? you still return a 404 header on your error page i assume?

Comment: @jmort253, I'm happy with adding robots.txt, just wasn't sure if I should be doing it through kohana or .htaccess as a best practice.

Comment: @Dagon we redirect (302) on a missing page to present a "pretty" error page. Google webmaster tools clearly indicates that it needs a 404 to accept the file as not there, 302 causes indexing problems as per a warning message in webmaster tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the file. If .htaccess is configured correctly, the Kohana framework only comes to action if there is no 'direct hit' on the requested file.

Comment: Just create the file where? In the same root folder as kohana's index.php? Is that a normal best practice?

Comment: In that same folder indeed. Easiest thing and common sense. It's a waste to load the framework each time a crawler comes by. It's just a static file, isn't it? I don't recall to have ever seen robots.txt being served through a framework.